# How can I send a message when I drag over an element

Tags: elm

I have a fairly simple elm application

https://github.com/chrisortman/team-player

I can't figure out how to implement something that would let me click down in a table cell and drag over several other cells to select them.

It seems like onMouseOver is what I would want but I'm not sure how to combine that with the Mouse.isDown signal. I can combine Mouse.isDown and Mouse.position but then I don't know how to tie the position back to the table cell.

I think this idea gets me close...

```
import Mouse
import Html exposing(..)
import Html.Attributes exposing(style)
import Html.Events exposing(onMouseOver,onClick)
import Signal exposing(..)

positionWithButton2 = 
  Signal.map3 (,,) Mouse.isDown Mouse.position mouseEvents.signal
  |> Signal.filterMap positionIfDown (0,0)

--positionWithButton = 
--  Signal.map2 (,) Mouse.isDown Mouse.position
--  |> Signal.map positionIfDown

font : List (String, String)
font =
    [ ("font-family", "futura, sans-serif")
    , ("color", "red")
    , ("font-size", "2em")
    ]

type ElementAction 
  = Hover Int
  | NoHover

mouseEvents = Signal.mailbox NoHover

background : List (String, String)
background =
    [ ("background-color", "rgb(245, 245, 245)")
    ]

positionIfDown (isDown,position,hover) =
  case (isDown,hover) of
  (True, Hover x) -> Just (x,x)
  (True, NoHover) -> Just position
  (False, Hover x) -> Just position
  _ -> Nothing


view pos =
  div [ ] 
    [ p [ style (font ++ background)] [text (toString pos)]
    , h1 [onMouseOver mouseEvents.address (Hover 10)]
        [text "Magic"]
    , Html.button
        [ onClick mouseEvents.address NoHover]
        [text "Stop"]
    ]

main : Signal Html
main =
  Signal.map view positionWithButton2
```

Answer (score 3):

You will, I fear, need to do something a little more involved.

Before even attempting the elm version, we should really think about the javascript events that will fire as a user attempts to drag across multiple cells.

```
___________________
|(0,1)|(1,1)|(2,1)|
|_____|_____|_____| 
|(0,0)|(1,0)|(2,0)|
|_____|_____|_____|
```

Let's say someone starts to drag from cell `(1,1)`. We'll get an initial `mousedown` event, and then we'll start to receive `mousemove` events. What happens as we continue to drag, into cell `(1,2)`, say? Well, `(1,2)` *won't* receive a 'click' or a 'mousedown' event, but `mouseenter` and `mouseover` will fire, and `mousemove` should continue to fire, and I *think* its `target` attribute will change to be cell `(1,2)`.

So, what do we need to do to work out what is highlighted in elm land? Handily I see you are already using elm-html - we're going to have to make fairly hefty use of its `Events` part.

N.B I've put this together without the aid of a compiler, so there may be some errors; the shape feels about right though.

First off, we'll need this snippet:

```
import Json.Decode exposing ((:=), Decoder)
targetId : Decoder String
targetId = ("target" := ("id" := J.string))
```

This will decode the id of the target element from a given event.

We'll need the following event definition

```
data Event = SelectStart String
           | SelectContinue String
           | SelectCancel
```

and a mailbox to send them around

```
events : Signal.Mailbox (Event)
events = Signal.mailbox SelectCancel
```

Each cell will need to be given an `id` that has the coordinate information in it (`cell-0-1`, `cell-1-1`, etc), and the following events:

```
import Html.Events exposing (on)

on 'mousedown' targetId (\id -> Signal.message events.address (SelectStart id))
on 'mousemove' targetId (\id -> Signal.message events.address (SelectContinue id))
```

This should give you enough information to work out what has been selected by appropriately acting on the events that turn up on `events.signal`. N.B You may also want to attach to some other elements the ability to cancel the existing selection without beginning another; I am not sure quite what you're trying to achieve, though :-)

Your model should have a field that looks a bit like:

```
type alias SelectRange = ((Int, Int), (Int, Int)) 

type alias Model = {
    selectState : Maybe SelectRange
}
```

as we receive the first `SelectStart` event, we work out the coordinate from the id string (let's say it's `(0,0)`), and change selectState to `Just ((0,0), (0,0))`. `SelectContinue` events then start to turn up; we'll ignore them while they still refer to `(0, 0)`, but when one arrives for `(0,1)`; we examine the existing select state and decide it should now be `Just ((0,0),(0,1))`. Writing the `update` function in total is tricky (the user might drag in one direction and then the reverse), but not impossible.

On the assumption that selected cells are rendered differently to unselected ones, we can hand `selectState` to the view function, and as each cell is rendered, it can check to see whether it is selected or not and behave appropriately.

I hope that's enough information to get you going; if anything is unclear, please ask :-)